# Summarizing and grouping rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, filtering, summarize

I'm and R novice and I'm currently working with a data frame in R that looks like the following.

```
City p54_1 p54_2 p54_3 p54_4 p54_5 p54_6 p54_7 p54_8 p54_9 p54_10 p54_11 p54_12
19   Apodaca     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0      0      1      1
46   Apodaca     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      1      1      1
51   Apodaca     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0
57   Apodaca     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0
86   Apodaca     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      1      1      1
89   Apodaca     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0      0      1      0
p54_13 p54_14
19      0      1
46      0      1
51      0      0
57      0      0
86      1      1
89      1      1
```

I'm working with several cities and columns related to them. All these columns have values that are codified, meaning they're either 0, 1, 8, or 9. I'm trying to find out how many "1"s there are per city, and throughout all columns and rows per city name.

However, most R code I try is mainly focused on analyzing and comparing individual columns, such as

```
nrow(subset(dataframe, City == "Apodaca" & p54_1 == 9)) for example,
```

or summarising other points of data, such as the following code:

```
EAV21 %>%     group_by(City) %>% summarise(cnt = n()) %>% mutate(freq = formattable::percent (cnt/sum(cnt)))
```

which displays the following

```
A tibble: 11 × 3
City                       cnt freq      
<chr>                    <int> <formttbl>
1 Apodaca                    351 9.06%     
2 Cadereyta Jiménez          353 9.11%     
3 García                     354 9.13%     
4 General Escobedo           354 9.13%     
5 Guadalupe                  354 9.13%      
6 Juárez                     354 9.13%     
7 Monterrey                  354 9.13%     
8 San Nicolás de los Garza   354 9.13%     
9 San Pedro Garza García     346 8.93%     
10 Santa Catarina             354 9.13%     
11 Santiago                   348 8.98%
```

This table is pretty hefty for other analyses, but it doesn't display the total amount of observations of each city ("Municipio"; It only displays the total count of every time the city's name appears in the data frame), but it is close to what I'm trying to obtain.

I've tried repeating nrow(subset(dataframe, City == "cityname" & columnname == value)) per city name, per column name, and per value, and adding these results to variables created by myself in R. While this could certainly be viable, I'm sure there must a cleaner way of calculating what I'm seeking.

**What kind of code would allow me to obtain the amount of "0"s and "1s" present in each city name's rows, all throughout the columns p54_1 to p54_14 to obtain their frequency percentages?**

Answer (score 1):

We could do it like this:

Bringing data in long format and then using `count`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-City) %>% 
  count(City, value)

 City    value     n
  <chr>   <int> <int>
1 Apodaca     0    40
2 Apodaca     1    44
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `across()` with `dplyr` to do things across columns. For example,

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    cnt_1 = rowSums(across(-City) == 1),
    cnt_0 = rowSums(across(-City) == 0)
  )
#       City p54_1 p54_2 p54_3 p54_4 p54_5 p54_6 p54_7 p54_8 p54_9 p54_10 p54_11 p54_12 cnt_1 cnt_0
# 19 Apodaca     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0      0      1      1     7     5
# 46 Apodaca     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      1      1      1    10     2
# 51 Apodaca     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0     3     9
# 57 Apodaca     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0     1    11
# 86 Apodaca     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      1      1      1    12     0
# 89 Apodaca     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0      0      1      0     5     7
```

You could follow this up with `%>% group_by(City)` to add the counts from various rows, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your data frame is called `df`, this may be a solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  # cast all `p*` columns longer:
  pivot_longer(starts_with("p")) %>%
  # for each `City` and `value` combination ...:
  group_by(City, value) %>%
  # ... count:
  summarise(N = n())
```

Comment: yes, I've seen that from your post